# Make UIButton disappear after clicking it?

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch

I want after I click on a button it should disappear, but I want it that it also will be back in a few seconds.

After I click on the button, the time should be random (something like 2 or 5 seconds) before the button will come back.

The buttons action is `@IBAction func increaseCount(sender: AnyObject)`.

Comment: show more of your code... what is currently inside your `@IBAction` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below will hide the button for a random time between 2-5 seconds

```
@IBAction func increaseCount(button: UIButton) -> Void {
  button.isHidden = true

  let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(Double((arc4random_uniform(3) + 2)) * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
  dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    button.isHidden = false
  }
}
```

.hidden was changed to .isHidden in Swift 3

Answer (score 0):

if you just want it to go away it is

`button.isHidden = true`

Note: they changed it from `.hidden` to `.isHidden`